# Worklight app authenticity is failing for some situations

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing WL application using WL enterprise ver (6.2.0.1) fix pack 1.

We have implemented the App authenticity correctly 3 months ago and everything was working (No changes been made on authenticationConfig.xml).

Today, all our applications are failing on App authenticity for both environments (Dev,QA), error on WL server:

```
[3/10/15 14:13:43:821 EDT] 000000d3 AuthenticityL I  

com.worklight.core.auth.ext.appauth.AuthenticityLoginModuleImpl login FWLSE0127E:        
Authenticity check failed for application 'APPNAME'. sharedData = ca.company.AppIDiPhone , challengeData = 514738N882129N341449C605766C744589X0355BCA6S214650C169432N928395XEDA8943BS085337C264942N797462X2B0C6AA2S462207X9035E6C7S . [project Name]
    [3/10/15 14:13:43:853 EDT] 000000d3 LoginContext  W com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext invokeLoginModule FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'wl_authenticityRealm': login fail [project Name]
```

The error appears on the time of launching the app and it is inconsistent, it happens (1/10)times.

AuthenticationConfig.xml:

```
 <securityTests>
        <customSecurityTest name="CompanyTestmobile">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

    <webSecurityTest name="CompanyTest">
        <testUser realm="CompanyRealm" />
    </webSecurityTest>
    <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
        <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>           

</securityTests>
```

Application-descriptor.xml (For iPhone):

```
<iphone applicationId="AppID" bundleId="ca.company.AppIDiPhone" securityTest="CompanyTestMobile" version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="false"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="true"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="true" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
    </security>
</iphone>
```

All our configuration is matching the WL document.

PS1: according to my understanding that the appAuthenticity will fail always or will not fail at all. why it is failing sometimes and working other times.

PS2: the deployment on our servers are not touchable and can't be modified once we deploy. That's a confirmation that the environment is stable and secured.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Do you have several versions of the application deployed (i.e. iphone v1.0, v1.1)? 2) Double-check that the application was not deployed with an incorrect developer certificate or bundleId 3) If you are using a cluster of servers, make sure there are no other suspicious errors in the server logs.

Comment: we are using one version of the app (1.0)(validated on WL console). the application is deployed with the correct bundleID (enterprise certificate and has not been changed). we are using one cluster and one node. we have also validated the Data power and the IHS servers and all are passing the connection without any errors. We recycled the cluster, but the issue still appears (1/10) times. if there is any issues with the dev certificate or bundleID, the app will fail all the time.   (The issue appears on Android too)

Comment: Did you make any changes to the DataPower configuration in the last 3 months that you mentioned? Can you try w/out DataPower and confirm the 1/10 failure no longer happens?

Comment: I will use a close local environment and deploy the app on iPhone device which will connect directly to my local dev server. and validate. Can I validate App authenticity on Development server not enterprise one?

Comment: Authenticity cannot be tested using the Eclipse Studio plug-in.

Comment: Any news about this issue?

Comment: Still in PMR, we are in phase of activating authenticity logging on the server "com.worklight.auth" to FINEST and need to send the log again. BTW this issue appears on our QA env only and we could't replicate it on Dev, even both are exactly the same.

Comment: Okay. I suspect something in the network traffic...

Comment: What do you mean by network traffic, are you suspecting something wrong with Data power or IHS? what is the percentage of their impact on app authenticity?

Comment: I have no idea. I did ask you to test without DP/IHS to see if anything changes. You did not get back to me about it...

Comment: QA Env is not for testing or multiple deployment, and since we couldn't reproduce the issue on Dev, I couldn't test outside Data power or IHS.

Comment: IMO it's a test you should consider doing.

Comment: How is the PMR progressing?

Comment: They are reviewing the logs.

Comment: What is the PMR number?

Comment: Idan, As you know that we can't share the code with IBM. And they mentioned that there is a possibility that the authenticity will fail if we are making a call to the WL before establishing the connection. Our developers stated that no calls being made before connecting to WL. 10d ago we did video conference with IBM to reproduce the issue and they are waiting for us to provide the decrypted data which is in progress. In your experience, where is the possibility to make a call to WL server before the connection.? I just want to validate our developer statement. thank you.

Comment: For example a `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` call before a `WL.Client.connect` call.

Comment: in main.js I have for example the following code: `function getLanguage() {
 return (WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() || 'en');
}                                                                                                                function wlCommonInit() {WL.Client.connect({
  onSuccess : function(response) {
   // kept blank as we do not need to perform anything on success
  }, ......}`, Does this match your example?

Comment: No, that's fine. Application authenticity check happens on the very first request sent from the application to the server.

Comment: My main.js doesn't contain any `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`. it is only contains the `WL.Client.connect`. the `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` is being used in a different JS file in a different directory. According to my understanding, when I launch the application, the first file get executed is main.js, Am I right? If no, please give me the correct sequence of the files that being executed one after another. if yes, then I believe we are not using any API before establishing the connection.

Comment: You are thinking about it completely the wrong way Hussam. Your "files order" does not matter. When the application launches, the Worklight framework is being initialized. Once its done, wlCommonInit is called. This function is typically in main.js. That's it. I don't know what you do in your app and it doesn't matter, as long as you make sure that before ANY REQUEST TO THE SERVER, you have FIRST called WL.CLIENT.CONNECT. After that is done, you can call any other request you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PMR this appeared to have happened due to a race condition triggered by applicative code calling to adapter requests simultaneously , which led to infrequent failures of the authenticity tests.

The customer adjusted their code to not cause a race condition after which the issue could no longer be reproduced.